# Why do we refresh computer

Tags: refresh

Why do we refresh computer?What does 60Hz refresh mean?Why do only computers provide an option to refresh and not mobiles or other devices.Please explain it to me.[image]

Answer (score 1):

We do not refresh computers at 60 Hz. Just the *display* refreshes itself at this rate.

## 60Hz (and more)

The 60Hz refresh rate you mention is something originating from the old [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube)s (big TV like monitors). The picture on those got drawn via an electron beam and fades soon after. To keep a steady image on the screen you needed to re-draw (refresh) this at least 50 times per second.

At least, since 50, 60, 70 and 75Hz where often used values. Fewer than 50Hz refreshes and you start to notice lag. 50/60Hz suffices and matched the power grids in most countries. >60Hz was often used in countries where the screen refresh and [fluorescent lamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp) would interfere.

Today we mostly used LCDs (TN, IPS, ...) and this is mostly used to indicate how fast information on a LCD is updated. E.g. when you move your mouse it will not show this new position on the screen until it redraws that information.

---

## mobiles:

No idea what you mean with that? Laptops (same answer as computers), mobile phones (different answers per phone model)? Tablets (they do use the same setup as computers but are likely more locked down). Ebook readers (probably using eink, which changes things), ...

---

## Refreshing computers.

To add to the confusion windows introduced something called a 'refresh' to windows 8. [It does not to the same thing as about but it restores some OS files.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc).

Comment: I want to show you a picture on the refresh rate...how do I upload one?

Comment: [Edit](http://superuser.com/questions/969051/why-do-we-refresh-computer/969052#969052) the post and control-G

Comment: @hennes-See my question above.It shows 60Hz refresh rate.